# What is the CRLB of the hyper-parameters of a Gaussian process kernel by using marginal likelihood

Tags: likelihood, gaussian-process, hyperparameter, bounds

I want to derive the CRLB of the hyper-parameters contained in a covariance kernel of a Gaussian process. My kernel looks like the following.

$$ K(t, t^{\prime}) = \exp(-\sigma^2/2 (t - t^{\prime})^2) \exp(i \mu (t - t^{\prime})) $$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.
The parameters are:
$$ \Theta = [\mu, \sigma] $$

The vectors $\mathbf{t}$ and $\mathbf{t^{\prime}}$ are basically the same. Therefore, $K$ is a Hermitian matrix.

The marginal log likelihood is known to be:

$$ \ln{(z|\Theta)} = -\frac{1}{2} z^{H}K^{-1}z -\frac{1}{2} |K| $$

As the parameters are inside the $K$, I am confused how to find the double derivative to compute the CRLB based on this likelihood. Any ideas would be appreciated.

==== What I have tried so far for $\mu$ ==========

$$ \frac{\partial \ln{(z|\mu)} }{\partial \mu} = -\frac{1}{2} z^{H}K^{-1} \frac{\partial K}{\partial \mu} K^{-1} z - \frac{1}{2} |K| \textbf{tr}\left( K^{-1} \frac{\partial K}{\partial \mu} \right) $$

The trace of $\left( K^{-1} \frac{\partial K}{\partial \mu} \right)$ is $0$.

$$ \frac{\partial \ln{(z|\mu)} }{\partial \mu} = -\frac{1}{2} z^{H}K^{-1} \frac{\partial K}{\partial \mu} K^{-1} z $$